Как получить список ВСЕХ писем разбитых по папкам mail.ru с помощью imaplib python?
Раньше я получал список письмо командой
a = imap.select('INBOX')[1][0]
, теперь письма распределили по папкам и e.mail.ru/inbox пустой. Мне же необходимо взять ПОСЛЕДНЕЕ письмо, которое пришло на почту.
Может, можно обратиться сразу ко всем письмам? Если да, то как?
